# Passing an array to query parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hi Friends I am trying to merge two json arrays i have tried concat and merge method but it's not giving the correct output please suggest something...

```
var set_image=[{"id":"aerobics"},{"id":"kick boxing"}]
var item_json=[{"id":"net ball"},{"id":"floor ball"}]
```

Merged Array

```
var finalArray =[{"id":"aerobics"},{"id":"kick boxing"},{"id":"net ball"},{"id":"floor ball"}]
```

Here is my javascript

```
var item = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("test"));
var item_json = JSON.stringify(item) ;

var page= <?php echo $json_value; ?>;
var set_image=JSON.stringify(page) ;


//var image=set_image.concat(item_json);
var image= $.concat(set_image, item_json)


window.location.href = "modal.php?ids=" + image;
```

Comment: This looks exactly what concat is supposed to to. What do you expect?

Comment: There's no need to use the jQuery concat, when the native JS method exists.

Comment: @RegisPortalez  i want to merge both the array concat method is not merging

Comment: @Rahul then please give us an example of your required result.

Comment: What do you mean merging? please add the expected output

Comment: expected output  [{"id":"aerobics"},{"id":"kick boxing"},{"id":"net ball"},{"id":"floor ball"}]   coming like this [{"id":"aerobics"},{"id":"kick boxing"}],[{"id":"net ball"},{"id":"floor ball"}]

Comment: That makes no sense, the expected output and the output you get are *exactly the same*....

Comment: see carefully in expected output all the value are inside one array but right now i am getting output like this [arr1],[arr2] concat() is not working.

Comment: I can guarantee you that `concat` is working absolutely fine and that the issue lies elsewhere in your code - for example the appending of the array to a string as I mentioned in my answer. Unfortunately you're not giving anyone enough further information to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the merged array to json string after that encode it using **[`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)** to pass in url

```js
var set_image=[{"id":"aerobics"},{"id":"kick boxing"}]
var item_json=[{"id":"net ball"},{"id":"floor ball"}]

var arr= set_image.concat(item_json);

window.location.href  = "modal.php?ids=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Comment: my url is coming like this  http://localhost/carc_app/user/modal.php?ids=%5B%22%5B%7B%5C%22id%5C%22%3A%5C%22yoga%5C%22%7D%2C%7B%5C%22id%5C%22%3A%5C%22aerobics%5C%22%7D%5D%22%2C%22%5B%7B%5C%22id%5C%22%3A%5C%22net%20ball%5C%22%7D%2C%7B%5C%22id%5C%22%3A%5C%22floor%20ball%5C%22%7D%5D%22%5D

Comment: @Rahul :  json string encoded to pass in url... now you can parse it from serveer... `json_decode($_GET['ids']);`

Answer (score 0):

`concat()` is exactly what you need, however your usage of it is incorrect:

```
var set_image = [{ "id": "aerobics" },{ "id": "kick boxing" }]
var item_json = [{ "id": "net ball" },{ "id": "floor ball" }]
var image = set_image.concat(item_json);
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/q5e83jud/)

Also note that your final line appending the `image` array to a string will not have the desired effect as it will just append `[object Object]` multiple times. I would guess you instead want to loop through the array and append each `id` value individually.

Comment: your answer is correct but still it is coming like this [{"id":"yoga"},{"id":"aerobics"}],[{"id":"net ball"},{"id":"floor ball"}]

Comment: for me it's returning array separated by comma like this [],[]

Comment: In the `console.log`?

Comment: I have pagination , on first page i have selected 2 values after that i have clicked for next page on second page i am selecting 2 more values after that i have clicked confirm butoon and sent all the value in url as a single array ....sorry for mistakes